# Not showing correct view after zooming on GMSMap

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, mkmapview, gmsmapview

I have been using **GMSMap** in my app. I am showing current location in Map. But after zooming the Map it does not show city and state, also path is not visible in the map. I want to I have zooming on map and clear map in the present states and city's. Please assist me for my issue

## I am used this code

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:22.6987 longitude:75.8817 zoom:0];
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView;

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.6987, 75.8817);
marker.title = @"indore";
marker.snippet = @"India";
marker.map = mapView;
```

[Now Show Look like please see ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMnII.png)

Comment: Your ques. is still not clear, can you tell me what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: sorry for that but I have been recheck my API then show successfully any location. :)

Comment: So the task is done ?

Comment: Yes absolutely done :)

Comment: @user12345, In My app also showing similar your image.
Why its happening?
What can i change in API?